# Using Query String To Change Form Value

Tags: javascript, url-encoding

I've got a sales funnel where I ask for an address through the Google API, it returns the query string similar to this:

```
 123+Yonge+Street%2C+Toronto%2C+ON%2C+Canada
```

I've found a function which I've used to grab the query string like this:

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
if (!url) {
  url = window.location.href;
}
name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
    results = regex.exec(url);
if (!results) return null;
if (!results[2]) return '';
return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

I've then gotten to display the Query String properly formatted (without special characters) how I would like in a Div on the page with the ID address_name but when I try to add the same address into an input field with the same variable it's resulting in having the input text as 123+Yonge+Street+Toronto+ON+Canada.

```
var address = getParameterByName('address');
document.getElementById("address_name").innerHTML=address;
document.getElementById("formaddress").value = address;
```

While it works perfectly with inserting into a DIV when I try to put it into an input field the spaces are replaced with a "+". Is there some sort of special formatting or rule I'm missing using an input form instead of a Div?

Comment: Can you post the code where you assign the value to the input field?

Comment: @Psi it's already there

Comment: I'm getting blind i guess...

Comment: What type of element is the one with ID `formaddress`? If it's an `<input>`, what is its `type`?

Comment: Maybe place the .replace outside of the call to decodeURIComponent: `return decodeURIComponent(results[2]).replace(/\+/g, " ");`

Comment: @Psi shouldn't make a difference (I just checked)

Comment: Thanks all, the <input> is text for testing at the moment but essentially what I'm trying to do is assign it to a a hidden input.

Comment: It is working now, I had originally changed the hidden input to text and that seems to have been the problem, not sure why hidden is different but that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

How does your code differ from this working example?

```js
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
if (!url) {
  url = window.location.href;
}
name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
    results = regex.exec(url);
if (!results) return null;
if (!results[2]) return '';
return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var address = getParameterByName('address', '?address=123+Yonge+Street%2C+Toronto%2C+ON%2C+Canada');
document.getElementById("address_name").innerHTML=address;
document.getElementById("formaddress").value = address;
```

```html
<div id="address_name"></div>
<input id="formaddress" type="text">
```

Comment: While this would make a great comment (with a JSFiddle example), it doesn't really answer the question

Comment: I figured that if OP provided some more information I could adjust the answer to be more helpful. You are probably right that this would have been better suited to a comment but I prefer to use SO snippets over JSFiddles.

Comment: Id doesn't differ by the looks of it, there must be something else going on within the page.  It's being used through Clickfunnels and the form is integrated through activecampaign, guessing there's something happening not related to the code maybe.  Page is sell.2percentrealtyedge.ca if anyone wants to look.  There never seems to be a value assigned to the input Im trying to change unless manually set.

Comment: As a last resort, you can always do `input.value = address.replace(/\+/g, ' ')`. That should never produce pluses in the input value, no matter happened to your `address` string along the way. It's a workaround but at least it should work.

Comment: It's working here and there, there was an issue with having changed the original input type from hidden to text, not sure why but it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Code was correct, there was an issue with the input field being hidden instead of a text field.